# Eigenvalues of a simple random matrix (Girko's circular law?)

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I am considering a real random matrix whose off-diagonal entries are i.i.d. and normally distributed (with non-zero mean and non-unit variance), and whose diagonal entries are uniform and deterministic. When I calculate its eigenvalues, I get they are distributed as a circle (see figure), plus an isolated eigenvalue which is due to the Perron–Frobenius theorem. I know about the Girko's circular law, but this is usually proved when all the entries (not only the off-diagonal ones) are i.i.d. with zero mean and unit variance. Do you know about any proof or article of the circular law in the case of the matrix I have just described?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

**EDIT**

This is the only explanation I have found (from the book ***Food Webs and Biodiversity: Foundations, Models, Data***), even if it doesn't sound very rigorous:

[image]

where (probably) $Var\alpha_{12}$ and $E\alpha_{12}$ are the variance and the mean of the off-diagonal entries.

Comment: I cannot answer your question but I'm researching a similar problem myself. I believe the following paper is relevant: http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4818 - see also a blog post by the author at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/outliers-in-the-spectrum-of-iid-matrices-with-bounded-rank-permutations/ . Non-zero means are addressed towards the end of the blog post, in the paragraph starting "The same method can handle some other bounded rank perturbations."

Comment: Many thanks Nathaniel, I'll have a look at the links you suggest!